# iTerm 2 Doesn't Start Up With Proper Default Profile

Tags: iterm2

When iTerm 2 starts up it uses a profile called "default" that doesn't exist.

[image]

If I open a new tab, I get the behavior I expected on start:

[image]

Here are my profiles:

[image]

What keeps my real default from loading on start?

Comment: You didn't say which version of iTerm2 you are using, but from the UI it seems to be dated. I would encourage you to switch to nightly or at least beta. I've been on the nightly channel for years with hardly any crashes.

Comment: This is version 2.1.4 - the current, stable version.

Comment: And that *is* dated, as I said.

Comment: What is the current version? Check for updates... returns nothing new.

Comment: That's the current stable. Development happens on 2.9 instead (I think I've heard that the plan is to release 3.0 by the end of this year, but I'm not sure). Switch to beta or nightly to enjoy the latest and greatest. There's a "prompt for test-release updates" setting in Preferences->General. For new features in nightly (and hence the upcoming version 3), there's a features and screenshots page on the iTerm2 website.

Comment: I'm am trying to work through a similar issue where I update a profile, but the old version is cached by the window arrangement, and advice from somewhere told me to 'refresh' them somehow :P.  I'm on 3.0.15 currently, Mac 10.12.3.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by an "Arrangement" setup that was loaded with iTerm. Once I removed that the default profile would load correctly =D [image]

Comment: Thanks for that, @PhilHdt, sadly, it didn't help for me. My iTerm version is up to 3.0.14.