# How can I update/refresh my iTerm2 profiles being cached in my Default Window Arrangement?

Tags: macos, iterm2

Wasn't sure if I should post this on the Apple SE boards, but since it's not first-party software, I'll keep it here.

Can't find out where I got my original piece of advice, but it told me that old profiles are cached in the window arrangement.  So I should have it open, open each window's/tab's/pane's/session's info panel (Cmd+i), and either select the same profile in the list and hit "Use Selected Profile', or change between another and back to the original on hitting that same button each time.  Then save over the window arrangement and reload to test.

I have all of my profiles updated.  I can see the new badge text reflected when I open iTerm2 again now after using the above inconvenient workaround.

Problem is I still have the wrong working directory.  I thought updating the profiles wasn't working at all, even with that technique, but I think it's just the working directory path now.

Found a possibly related link here: [StackOverflow - iTerm 2 Doesn't Start Up With Proper Default Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068960/iterm-2-doesnt-start-up-with-proper-default-profile)

Answer (score 0):

The technique above may still be needed, but I did not test without it carefully enough again this time.

The change needed was actually changed the current working directory in each session.  Even though I was trying to only operate on it through the Profiles section's field, that didn't seem to actually update the path upon loading the window arrangement.

If these circumstances are all accurate, then I think the iTerm2 handling of profiles in other objects needs some updating, maybe more references and less duplicate data that could become stale or different because of its separation, at least adding for the option of working this way based on user preference..